# does the gcc compiler have any relation with the OS scheduler?

Tags: kernel, compile, gcc, scheduling

All is in the title I want to know if is there any relation between the compiler and the scheduler ?

Comment: What makes you think it would? I mean, gcc is often used to compile the OS's scheduler, at least in the context of Linux. And it runs under the OS's scheduler, but that's true of all software.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you concerned that GCC-built binaries affect the scheduler negatively?

Comment: I want to know if the compiler knows about what the scheduler is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the compiler doesn't know anything about what the scheduler is doing. 
You could take the same compiler and run it
on different versions of Unix or Windows, or even DOS
(which didn't do scheduling in the sense that modern OSs do),
and the compilation results would be the same.